# Scala Fold Left with Two Parameter Types

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

How can I convert this basic function *func2* into a fold left in Scala?

Here is the iterative approach. I use two functions.

```
def func1(list1: List[foo], item: bar): List[foo] = {  
    does something to the list and returns it  
}

def func2(list1: List[bar]): List[foo] = {
    var newList = List[foo]() // starts with an empty list

    for (item <- list1){ //cycle through list
        newList = func1(newList, item)
    }
    return newList;
}
```

I want to iterate through a list item by item. Run it through a function at each item and set the result of that function to a list.

Then, keep running through the function, and use the new list (an accumulator) as the list I use the next iteration's function call.

I tried doing this:

```
def func2(list1: List[bar]): List[foo] = {    
    var newList = list1.foldLeft( (List[foo]() )(list1) => {return func1(_,_) } );
```

But it did not work. I know I am close, but the syntax is wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is all you need.

```
def func2(list1 :List[Bar]) :List[Foo] =
  list1.foldLeft(List.empty[Foo])(func1)
```

You don't want to use `return`. It's usually unneeded and sometimes it does things you don't expect.

Comment: You don't even need the lambda function... `def func2(list1: List[Bar]): List[Foo] = list1.foldLeft[List[Foo]](Nil)(func1)`

Comment: For those wondering, the original answer 

list1.foldLeft(List.empty[Foo]){case (nl,item) => func1(nl, item)} 

works perfectly, but not the shorthand version (in my case). Something to do with anonymous functions I believe...